# How to deal with variables when extracting methods in to smaller methods?

Tags: ruby, variables, class, scope, single-responsibility

This is an abstract question to clarify a refactoring concept in the ruby language.  Assume in the real world that there would be many more variables and method in the Furniture Class and Refinish method.

I have a Class called Furniture.

It has a method called '`refurnish(VarnishToUse, TimeToTake)`'.
This method has

```
varnish_cost = Varnish(VarnishToUse).price * TimeToTake
```

I want to extract out the cost calculation into

```
def VarnishCost
  price * TimeToTake
end
```

then the Furniture class can just have:

```
def Refurnish(VarnishToUse)
  varnish_cost = VarnishCost(VarnishToUse)
end
```

How do I pass in the VarnishToUse into VarnishCost?  Should the method be

```
def VarnishCost(Varnish)
...
end
```

or should I be setting an instance variable `@varnish = VarnishToUse` in the Refinish class and then just expect that instance variable to be available in the VarnishCost method as I showed above?  Does it make a difference if the other method is private? protected?

I am looking to minimize the use of variables and multiple responsibilities for a class (SRP).

Comment: I'd just pass 'Varnish' as the parameter into the VarnishCost() method. However, there can be a gazillion other aspects that may play a role and influence your decision. (Hence this as a comment and not as an answer.)

Comment: What if I have 4 other parameters? I know that more than 2 or three parameters is bad practice (number of combos to test).  So what would be good practice?

Comment: In these kinds of situations, I tend to optimize for the least amount of written code as a rough approximation for the desired result.

Comment: If the number of parameters becomes larger and you find similar combinations of parameters passed around that you might have identified a candidate for a class. Once turned into a class you can reduce the number of parameters again because you have found a higher level of abstraction. This doesn't work always but can be an indication for improving your domain model.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If these are all methods in the Furniture class, you don't need to "pass" anything, just access the methods:

```
class Furniture
  attr_accessor :time_to_take
  attr_accessor :varnish_to_use

  def varnish_cost
    varnish_to_use.price * time_to_take
  end

  def refurnish
    # varnish_cost * markup_percent + premium # if you want to affect the price more...
    varnish_cost
  end
end

class Varnish
  def self.price
    # default price
    10
  end
end

class BasicVarnish < Varnish
  def self.price
    5
  end
end

class PremiumVarnish < Varnish
  def self.price
    20
  end
end

so now:
f1 = Furniture.new(:time_to_take => 2, :varnish_to_use => BasicVarnish)
f1.refurnish => 10

f2 = Furniture.new(:time_to_take => 2, :varnish_to_use => PremiumVarnish)
f1.refurnish => 40
```

(PS I changed the names of the methods as it's a bit confusing having them as Constants)

Comment: could you expand a little more on the use of `attr_accessor :varnish_to_use` and how that will relate to getting price with `varnish_to_use.price`

Comment: attr_accessor is a Ruby method of short-cutting getter and setter methods. In the object I outlined, it's just part of the interface that relates a Varnish instance to a Furniture instance. Then you can access the Varnish's methods, such as ".price".

Answer (score 1):

> should I be setting an instance variable @varnish = VarnishToUse in the Refinish class

You should do this when there are some other functions in your `Refinish` class which can use `varnish`, too, and when having a somewhat "global" (in the context of your class) variable in your code does not give you a higher risk of malfunction (for example, when `varnish` does not change any more after first initialization). Especially the second condition should be fulfilled, otherwise pass `VarnishToUse` as a parameter.